# Select a Standard load balancer

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-load-balancer

I have a PowerShell script that create a VM (VM image) and then VM scal set with an load balancer. The script is working when I run the script on my local machine but when running the script through an Azure DevOps pipeline I’m getting a weird http 400 error.
To understand the error, I’m then recreated the steps the fails from the Azure Portal but getting this error message: Select a Standard load balancer as the virtual machine scale set is configured with multiple placement groups.
How do I set my load balancer to a “Standard load balancer”?

[image: Error in Azure load balancer]

Comment: I have solved my problem by adding sku on the various PowerShell cmdlets

Comment: Hello @Anders Dissing, can you please post the solution as an answer here ? It would be helpful for community

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT the solution is to add the sku parameter to the powershell cmdlets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You [@Anders Dissing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12729883/anders-dissing) , Posting your solution as an answer for reference of other community members.

While creating a Load balancer using powershell , you can add the sku parameter as standard as the virtual machine scale set configured with multiple placement group requires standard load balancer .

```
New-AzLoadBalancer -Name "MyLoadBalancer" -ResourceGroupName "MyResourceGroup" -Location "West US" -FrontendIpConfiguration $frontend -BackendAddressPool $backendAddressPool -Probe $probe -LoadBalancingRule $lbrule -Sku Standard -Tier Global
```

**Reference:**

[New-AzLoadBalancer (Az.Network) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/new-azloadbalancer?view=azps-6.3.0)